# Use regular expression in group_by

Tags: ruby, regex

I have data:

```
data = [["/","201408","41"],["/","201409","35"],["/","201410","59"],["/","201411","50"],["/","201412","79"],["/","201501","97"],["/","201502","85"],["/","201503","518"],["/","201504","251"],["/","201505","748"],["/","201506","916"],["/","201507","1008"],["/","201508","449"],["/","201509","235"],["/","201510","195"],["/","201511","229"],["/","201512","202"],["/","201601","142"],["/","201602","134"],["/","201603","17"]]
```

I want to group them by year, but I don't know how I can use a regex in `group_by`. I should look like this:

```
grouped = data.group_by { |row| row[1] }
```

but what's next? row[1] string is YYYYMM

Comment: row[1] string is YYYYMM

Comment: Write so in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a regex? Is this not what you're looking for?

```
data.group_by { |d| d[1][0..3] }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer hallucinations' answer, but if you still want to use regexes:
`data.group_by { |row| row[1].match(/^(\d{4})/).captures[0] }`

Not very clean, but it works.